# How to describe a school "house"

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

I am trying to find a French translation for the word 'house', in the context of school. In England, schools are divided into 'houses' of students, like a group- this may not be a literal, physical entity though. Google translate gives 'maison d'école' which I think is a bit too literal- is there a proper word for it?

Comment: What is a school "house"? Somewhere where the students sleep?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I edited my question for the definition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean "house" like "Gryffindor" in Harry Potter for example, it is translated as **maison**, so we do in fact use the literal translation ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, maybe "confrérie" (fraternities with names made up of Greek letters like "Delta Kappa Epsilon"...)
You can also say "fraternité" (for boys) or "sororité" for girls

Comment: Isn't it an US thing? never seen such thing in England